# If Data not exists - show (custom text)

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress CMS and CMB2 METABOXES and Custom fields. Its works perfect but when I'm making loop If data in metabox not exists , this script anyway rendering empty group field. I want to give the command to script, if it is empty ----> show my custom markup code. I have this

```
<?php $our_advantages_items = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'our_advantages_block_box', true );
                                        if( !empty( $our_advantages_items ) ) {
                                        foreach( $our_advantages_items as $our_advantages_item ) { ?>
                                    <div class="cey96zggvcich3">
                                      <div class="cey96zggvcich3_cvz">
                                        <h2><?php echo $our_advantages_item['our_advantages_block_heading']; ?></h2>
                                        <div class="io2ji39349959jeij">
                                          <?php echo wpautop( $our_advantages_item['our_advantages_block_content'], 1 ); ?>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php }
                                    } ?>
```

Will be happy for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you're asking, but just add an else to your if statement

```
<?php if( !empty( $our_advantages_items ) ) : ?>
     //If not empty write your html here

<?php else: ?>
    //If empty write your html here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to put this statement in my markup, but its not working. I'm sure your answer is right but how my code must look finally?  can you update your answer using my code? THANKS!

Comment: I just updated my answer to a different format that is a bit easier to work with. Try using this format instead as it's easier to work with. I honestly can't read the code you posted because the indentations are all out of wack